# Gridster in touch enable devices

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, touch, device, gridster

I am trying to figure out how to use [GRIDSTER](http://gridster.net) in touch enable devices. 
I have tried to use the [touch puch plugin](http://touchpunch.furf.com/) but it appears not working for me.
Does someone have experience with that?
Thank you in advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it depends of gridster. It's all about jQuery draggable. You can try to put simple `div` on you page and try the touch punch plugin.

If gredster is not required in your project you can also try [gridstack](https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js#touch-devices-support). It's working with touch punch plugin fine. And I'm actively developing and supporting it.

Comment: I have solved the problem just updating the gridster version.
Thank you for your answer.